# Laravel can not update value in time. Simultaneously requests

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-9, php-8

I have PHP 8.3, and Laravel 9 project.

I have a post route for updating the balance column value. And function in controller below

```
 public function loadFunds(FundToCardRequest $request)
{
    $user = auth()->user();
    $request['clientUsername'] = 'username';
    $request['username'] = $user->username;
    $sum = $request['amount'];
    $request['amount'] *= (1 - config('commissions.credit_card_from_wallet') / 100);
    $response = SomeService::post('updateBalace', $request->toArray())->collect();

    if ($response->get('code') == 200) {
        DB::transaction(function () use ($user, $request, $sum) {
            $balance = $user->wallets()->where('currency', 'USD')->first()->pivot->balance;
            $user->wallets()->updateExistingPivot(1, ['balance' => $balance - $sum]);

            $user->transactions()->create([
```

The function receives a custom request with the following rules.

```
public function rules()
{
    $balance_usd = auth()->user()->wallets()->where('currency', 'USD')->first()->pivot->balance;

    return [
        'amount' => ['numeric', 'required', new NotZeroAmount(), new SendMoneyBalance($balance_usd)],
        'cardId' => ['required'],
        'ArrayHashId' => ['required'],
    ];
}
```

There is a rule *SendMoneyBalance* that checking is the current balance enough to send *amount* of money.

The problem is the following. Sometimes clients can send two simultaneous requests. The first request take time for processing after which the balance should be decreased and the final amount in the balance should be not enough. But the second request passes the rules because while first balance can't update. After this two requests balance goes to a negative value.

Are there any techniques to prevent this kind of simultaneous request? Or something like await structures like in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

This is called a race condition and what you basically want to do is to create some sort or unique lock per request per user or your preference.

Example

```
Cache::lock('foo', 10)->block(5, function () {
    // Lock acquired after waiting a maximum of 5 seconds...
});
```

See [here](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/cache#managing-locks) for ref